# Can't load highcharts.js and highmaps.js (map.js don't work)

Tags: jquery, highcharts, javascript

In a single web page a need make 3 different plot with `highcharts.js` and `highmaps.js`. The first that I try is load both script, but obviously don't work. Reading the [HighMaps Doc](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started), if already have load Highcharts, instead of `highmaps.js` I have to load:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

So I try that but it does not work, I can't see the 3 plots, why?  This is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/fnbellomo/ds1r4mw3/), and this are the 3 plots: [plot 1](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/heatmap/), [plot 2](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/heatmap/) and [plot 3](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/heatmap/)
Thanks!

Comment: the fiddle seems to work for me

Comment: oh, no, just 2. you never explained what wasn't working, you just said "it does not work" what output did you get, and what ouput did you expect to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in the browser console window it is giving you [Highcharts Error 17](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17). To fix this error you need to include one more highcharts script. Add the following line and you'll be fine:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

Make sure to include this after you have already loaded jQuery and Highcharts.

A working fiddle can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ds1r4mw3/1/).